# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in Matcher.find because of incorrect length used

Tags: java, regex

Perhaps I don't see the forest for the trees, but I have a (to me) strange problem with `Matcher`.
I receive this error message while processing a StringBuilder:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10238
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.charAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:210)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.charAt(StringBuilder.java:76)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BnM.match(Pattern.java:5459)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1248)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:637)
```

The length of the StringBuilder and the String derived from it is beyond that:

```
length: 10269
length: 10269
```

This is my code:

```
    Matcher m = LINK_PATTERN.matcher(content);

    System.out.println("length: " + content.length());
    System.out.println("length: " + content.toString().length());

    int hits = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        ...
        content.replace(m.start("absolut"), m.end("absolut"), "");
        ...
    }
```

The line with `m.find()` is where the exception fires.

This problem occurs even during my tests where no threading / parallel processing is involved. The LINK_PATTERN is defined this way:

```
private static final Pattern LINK_PATTERN = Pattern.compile( ...
```

There is one hit for this pattern, but it is at position 7260 and not 10something.

Comment: Are you modifying the `content` while iterating on the matcher?

Comment: In addition to dotvav's question, did you try `LINK_PATTERN.matcher(content.toString());` to operate on an immutable instance? And what are you doing in the while loop's body?

Comment: @dotvav Yes, I am. I think you put me on the right trick and I added a `m = LINK_PATTERN.matcher(content);` to my loop in order to "reset" the matcher. But now I am searching for a more clever way to do this because it always starts to search at position 0 until I replaced all matches.

Comment: You don't use directly `replaceAll` so I guess there are side effects in the while loop other than removing some text from the input.

Comment: Use `find(int start)` and supply the appropriate index (which you have to calculate from the number of character lost/gained from the replacement)